How to show a sticky button after scrolling 200px without JavaScript?
my goal is to set the sticky div initially to visibility: hidden. After scrolling more than 200px, the button should appear with visibility: visible. Is there a workaround to achieve this only with CSS, without JavaScript? In pure CSS, there doesn’t seem to be a way to detect exact scroll distances like 200px. Any suggestions?
This is my example:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: azure;
}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sticky {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sticky a {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="sticky">
    <a href="#top">ScrollToTop</a>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>



I tried many things like a sticky spacer, semi-sticky with multiple elements, and so on. Unfortunately, nothing worked.

no there is not. CSS does not know the scroll position. I proberly will never know. For what reason? Why should CSS get more complex to include scripting tasks when you already have JS for it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_scroll-driven_animations offer a choice here.

How come JS can't be used? It's a relatively simple task

here is an example based on a grid layout , container querie and float to hide or show a toplink if the content is long enough https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyLGgYg That's about what css could do without js . to test through different browsers  demo set at average 150vh to start show a toplink

You can also use a grid-layout, container query (to toggle an hide/show) and float/clear-both to show & push down a sticky link if needed only:
example from my earlier comment with your HTML:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  background-color: azure;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  --d: 4rem;
  --m: 1rem;
  --showScrollTopAt: calc(100vh + 150px); /* valeur a reporter en dur le container querie, la variable ne passe pas */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  1fr ;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header ,
.container,
footer {
  grid-column:1;
}
header,footer {
 display:grid;
 place-content:center;
 font-size:5vw
}
.container:has(p #show:checked) {
  height:1500px;
}
/* container cell to query */
.sticky {
  container-type: size;
  container-name: divTopLink;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row:1/4;
  overflow: visible;
}
/* pushing floatting pseudo  */
.sticky::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: var(--showScrollTopAt);
  max-height: 100cqh;
}
.sticky a {
  clear: both;
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(100vh - var(--d) - 1rem);
  margin: 0 1rem 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--d);
  width: var(--d);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0007;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
  margin-left: calc(var(--d) * -1 - 1rem);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* ************* container Querie ****************** 
max-height must be equal to var(--showScrollTopAt) !!
*/

@container divTopLink (max-height : calc(100vh + 150px)) {
  .sticky::before,
  .sticky a {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* ***************** fin container Querie ********************* */
<header id="top">header</header>
<div class="container">container
  <p><label>Check to make me 1500px tall <input type="checkbox" id="show"> to reveal the top link</label></p>    
  </div>
<div class="sticky">
  <a href="#top">ScrollToTop</a>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>




CSS Scroll animation
It can be implemented similarly, but adjust it yourself.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: azure;
}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sticky {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sticky a {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;

  /* scroll animation */
  view-timeline-name: --subjectReveal;
  animation-timeline: --subjectReveal;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1ms;
}

/* scroll animation */
@keyframes appear {
  39% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }

  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <a href="#top">ScrollToTop</a>
    </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>



Using JS
It becomes simple and accurate.


const scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector('.sticky a');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 200) {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.add('visible');
  } else {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove('visible');
  }
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: azure;
}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sticky {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sticky a {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.sticky a.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scroll to Top 버튼</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="sticky">
    <a href="#top">ScrollToTop</a>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>




Here an pure css approach with explanation. To achieve this, we need to understand that position sticky always needs the space where it sticks. so we need to define the space where the stickyness happens first. If the content is below 100vh + 200px in this example the button will not be shown.
the coloring of the areas is just for demo purpose.
I took also the freedom to adapt the HTML. in your case main is the container and the sticky button need to go there.


/* header snippet only for the sake of completion */
header {  
  height: 40px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

main {
  height: 200vh; /* play here with the height of the page */
  background:#eaeaea;
  position:relative;
}

footer {
  background:#ffc;
  height:200px;
}

/* We define the Module to float outide of the main content */
.sticky-module {
  --sticky-btn-height: 200px;
  --sticky-start-position: (100vh + var(--sticky-btn-height));
  container-type: size;
  container-name: stickyModule;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right:20px;
  background:#08fa001A;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}

/* now define the Area were the Button should be sticky */
.sticky-area {
  margin-top: calc(var(--sticky-start-position)); /* move it below the start Postion */
  height:calc(100% - var(--sticky-start-position)); /* then calculate the new height */
  width: 200px;
  background:#fac5001A;
}

/* inside the new sticky area define a spacer that takes space before the button */
.sticky-spacer {
  width: 30px;
  height: calc(100% - var(--sticky-btn-height)); /* keep button inside of yellow area */
  background: #fa2a001A;
}

/* define sticky button */
.sticky-btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: var(--sticky-btn-height);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background:#00f;
}

/* if there is not enough space hide it,
   here we calculate the 100vh + 200px starting point + 200px height of the button so it won't get cut of
*/
@container stickyModule (height < calc(100vh + 400px))  {
  .sticky-btn {
    display:none;
  }
}
<header>Some header</header>
<main>
  Main Content
  
  <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio eius autem amet veniam. Quasi quos molestias alias quis vitae qui cupiditate dolorum. Reprehenderit tempore, ab itaque esse adipisci commodi amet?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio eius autem amet veniam. Quasi quos molestias alias quis vitae qui cupiditate dolorum. Reprehenderit tempore, ab itaque esse adipisci commodi amet?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio eius autem amet veniam. Quasi quos molestias alias quis vitae qui cupiditate dolorum. Reprehenderit tempore, ab itaque esse adipisci commodi amet?
    </p>
   <div class="sticky-module">
     <div class="sticky-area">
       <div class="sticky-spacer"></div>
       <div class="sticky-btn">Button</div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>



